# PhpStorm: get correct indentation for YAML code in a .html file

Tags: zurb-foundation, phpstorm, yaml, webstorm

I'm using Zurb Foundation's templating system Panini. It has the option to define data, which can then be inserted into parts of the template, in a block of YAML at the beginning of a .html file, delineated by three dashes.

I'm wondering if I can get PhpStorm/WebStorm to properly indent my YAML (or leave it alone). As it stands, every time I reindent a file, it removes all indentation from my YAML. YAML uses indentation to define it's structure, so changing my indentation breaks my code.

Here's an example of what a file might look like:

```
---
title: 'Awesome Example'
menu:
    -
        text: 'The best example'
        link: 'http://example.com'
    -
        text: 'Wikipedia'
        link: 'http://en.wikipedia.org'
---
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, etc.</p>
</div>
```

As a workaround, I can make my YAML valid JSON (using braces and brackets to delineate structure), so this isn't an earth-shatering disaster, but using indentation would be easier, if possible.

Comment: There is no built-in functionality that would allow to select **random** chunk of file/code and say -- "this is now YAML/CSS/whatever". Surely, there are Language Injection rules .. but it has to follow certain rules (e.g. injection inside this specific HTML/XML tag etc) -- based on your example (file is separated by simple `---`) it will not work. If anything -- such support should be implemented via custom plugin that, at parse time, can say "this section  between `---` should be treated as YAML".

Comment: P.S. In general it looks similar to OctoberCMS templates (maybe they use the same idea/engine). If you find plugin that supports it then it may also work for your case.

Comment: To be clear on my "OctoberCMS" reference: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27668 & https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31236 -- the overall idea is similar to your case. Unfortunately there were no feedback from original ticket authors so those tickets are in "incomplete" status (and therefore not implemented).